# Laravel 5.5 LaravelCollective Form in Blade - DatabasePresenceVerifier wrong SQL syntax

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravelcollective

LaravelCollective text field on a form in Blade template:

```
{!! Form::text('AssignmentType', ' ', ['class' => 'form-control form-check50']) !!}
```

Validator for UNIQUE generates this SQL command:

select count(*) as aggregate from [AssignmentType] where [AssignmentType] = Staff

The value entered into the form field is missing quotes in the SQL command generated by SQLserver driver for MSSQL. That makes SQL think its a column name not a string value.

With quotes added the command works as expected in MSSQL Studio.

Query built by DatabasePresenceVerifier

```
 +wheres: array:1 [▼
    0 => array:5 [▼
      "type" => "Basic"
      "column" => "AssignmentType"
      "operator" => "="
      "value" => "Staff"
      "boolean" => "and"
    ]
  ]
```

Is this a bug or is there something I'm missing in the LaravelCollective  form field?

Answer (score 0):

This problem went away once the correct database connection was being used.

From previous question about form validator:
You can add the connection to the validation rule like this 'unique:connection.table,column' – jfadich